Universe: Isolated or not?
Yesterday in our class, we were taught that an isolated system has the following boundaries: Non movable, adiabatic, impermeable. We were told that the universe can be considered an isolated system. My question is, how can we consider the universe and isolated system if the universe is constantly expanding? It would mean that the boundaries of the system is movable, which contradicts the properties of an isolated system.
This is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated!

Using the universe is not really helpful here. A silvered vacuum flask is surely a better example. (btw, if the universe is all there is it has to be 'isolated' but this is still silly)

This question is similar to: Why it is said that Universe is an isolated system?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The universe’s “boundaries” at infinity are not moving, although the apparent distance between two points on the boundary can appear to increase; this is a consequence of spacetime’s expansion, not motion of the boundaries. I suggest you read about the FLRW metric.

@controlgroup Since an infinite universe has no boundaries, it is meaningless to discuss their motion.

That's the bigger issue but my guess is that that issue is farther beyond what is directly pertinent here. Understanding that a boundless system can be isolated is more complex than understanding that the Universe is isolated in some sense, at least I think. I'm probably wrong.
